# Unable to access jpg in jsp

Tags: java, image, apache, jsp

There are **two** image files in my **webcontent/images** folder **the_logo.jpg** and **logo.png**

I am **able to access the .png** file

```
<img alt="Powerpay1" src="./images/logo.png"  width="250" height="50" />
```

but **unable to access the .jpg** file

```
<img alt="Powerpay" src="./images/the_logo.jpg"  width="250" height="50" />
```

How should I solve this?
Feel free to ask if any other information is needed.

**NOTE** : I am using Apache tomcat.

Comment: Check your browser's developer tool's network panel for the error

Comment: can you display other jpg or all jpg not working?

Comment: You are asking for JPG and you have written PNG in your code

Comment: It might just be that the jpeg image is not really jpg. It might be that the file name is wrong: case (a capital somewhere) or `.jpg.jpg`. Or it might be that the static content is delivered by servlet and in its URL mapping only images/*.png is listed.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam while accessing .png its not throwing error however while accessing .jpg its throwing 404

Comment: @user7294900 yes, it's throwing error for all .jpg but is working fine for all .png

Comment: @sForSujit I am asking for both .png and .jpg in my code

Comment: @JoopEggen I have double checked the file location, name and format.

Comment: do you use apache ?

Comment: @user7294900 Yes, I do use apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
<img alt="Powerpay1" src="../images/logo.png"  width="250" height="50" />

<img alt="Powerpay1" src="../images/the_logo.jpg"  width="250" height="50" />
```

> This code will take the cursor to the previous folder.
>
> If you have two nested folder, use `../../` or three nested folders, use `../../../`and so on to go to the root of the directory and browse respectly.

instead of

```
<img alt="Powerpay1" src="./images/logo.png"  width="250" height="50" />

<img alt="Powerpay1" src="./images/the_logo.jpg"  width="250" height="50" />
```

---

One more best way to doing it by using scriptlets

Ex:

```
<%
    String base = request.getContextPath() + "/";
    if (base == null || base.isEmpty()) {
        base = "/";
    }
%>

<img alt="Powerpay1" src="<%=base%>images/logo.png"  width="250" height="50" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache configuration can allow specific suffixes. see [mod_suffix](http://weitz.de/mod_suffix.html)

File in linux should be in a path as `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Try changing your files match patterns to add **jpg**:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|**jpg**|gif|css|php|html|js)$">
allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Where should I put this matcher pattern?

Comment: Inside /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf